# Reading wrong RGB values when I resize UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, resize, uiimage

I'm reading the RGB values of my UIImage (inputImage), this way:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = inputImage.CGImage;
NSData *data = CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef)));
unsigned char *pixels = (unsigned char *)[data bytes];

for(int i = 0; i < [data length]; i += 4) {
    int r = i;
    int g = i+1;
    int b = i+2;

    int rValue = (int)pixels[r];
    int gValue = (int)pixels[g];
    int bValue = (int)pixels[b];
}
```

It works perfect. But if I use a function for resizing the image before that piece of code, the values go wrong. For example, they say that a pixel is 255 blue, when it's 255 red. I think that the red and blue RGB channels are changed when I use the functions (I know, it has no sense).

This is the function that I use for resizing my image:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage2;
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
inputImage = [self imageWithImage:inputImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(inputImage.size.width, inputImage.size.height)];
```

This happens even if I resize to the same size I have. Something strange occurs with the data, but the result is correct, the image is resized correctly.
Anyone knows what's the problem?

Comment: In the first instance you are reading the image directly, in the second you are using a context. I guess the first is RGB, the other BGR. Use CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage) to confirm.

Comment: No... I use CGImageGetColorSpace(inputImage.CGImage) before and after using the resizing function, and returns the same value: kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB. But CGImageGetAlphaInfo changes from 5 to 2, CGImageGetBitmapInfo changes from 5 to 8194 (¿?), and CGImageGetBytesPerRow changes from 1068 to 1088 (it adds 20 bytes always, it doesn't matter what image I use). All with the same image, and using the function, but resizing to the same size.

Comment: Ok, now I used properly CGImageGetBitmapInfo... kCGBitmapByteOrderMask changes from NO to YES, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little changes from NO to YES, and kCGBitmapByteOrder16Big changes from NO to YES. The other constants don't change, and their value is NO, except kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask (YES).

Answer (score 0):

It defaults to BGR from RGB.  OpenCV does the same transposing of channels.